# Project settings screen in Xcode 8?

Tags: xcode, settings

Does anyone know how to get back the Xcode 7-style project settings in an existing project in Xcode 8? This is so weird: projects that have been created in Xcode 7 (before I upgraded to 8) now have a new style project settings page (which is very confusing, I can't find anything in there). When I create a new project in Xcode 8, the project settings page looks exactly like in Xcode 7 (with the 7 or 8 tabs next to each other, starting with General on the very left). Why am I not seeing this settings page in my older projects which I created in Xcode 7?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was struggling with this as well. Follow the steps:

1. Press your apps project at the top of the far left menu like you normally do
2. By default you'll be on the PROJECT section, which has a new look. Below it, you'll see TARGET, select that and you'll see the screen that you are used to.

I believe this is what you're after. Let me know if not.

[image]

Comment: Yes!! Thank you so much! Stupid thing is I actually tried this on my own when I noticed the "Targets" tab, but I looked too fast, which made me miss the familiar tabs at the top of the screen. That was really clumsy, but thanks for pointing me that way again!